# Error pertaining to installation of PHP 7.2 in AIX 7.2 machine while running "make install"

Tags: apache, aix, php-7.2, make-install

I am installing PHP 7.2 on AIX 7.2 machine from source along with Apache 2.4. Used the following command's in the order. No errors in step 1 and 2.

1) `./configure --prefix=/opt/php/install --with-config-file-path=/opt/php/install --with-apxs2=/opt/apache/install/bin/apxs --with-openssl=/opt/freeware/openssl --with-curl=/opt/curl/install --with-png-dir=/opt/freeware --with-zlib-dir=/opt/freeware --with-iconv=/opt/freeware --enable-mbstring --with-gd --with-gmp=/opt/gmp/install --enable-cli --disable-phar`

2) `make`

3) `make install.`

Getting the following error. How to resolve this?

```
        echo '\
\
        echo '\
\
Installing PHP SAPI module:       apache2handler
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /opt/apache/install/bin/apxs line 222.
/opt/apache/install/build/instdso.sh SH_LIBTOOL='/opt/apache/install/build/libtool' libphp7.la /opt/apache/install/modules
rm -f /opt/apache/install/modules/libphp7.so
/opt/apache/install/build/libtool --mode=install install libphp7.la /opt/apache/install/modules/
libtool: install: install .libs/libphp7.a /opt/apache/install/modules/libphp7.a
find: bad status-- /opt/apache/install/modules/libphp7.a
install: File libphp7.a was not found.
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=131072
.
make: The error code from the last command is 1.

Stop
```

I think it's not able to copy the libphp7.a file from ./libs folder of PHP to apache/install/modules.

Comment: One thing you could try: repeat every compilations with `LDFLAGS=-Wl,-brtl`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond I ran "make LDFLAGS=-Wl, -brtl" only for PHP. It failed with same error. Do I need to run the same command for Apache, curl etc? What is the significance of "LDFLAGS=-Wl, -brtl" ?

Comment: You might try, but you should realize that compiling on AIX _is_ hard, you will face countless problems. (I've written some words about AIX, it might be interesting: http://lzsiga.users.sourceforge.net/aix-linking.html )

Answer (score 0):

It‘s an AIX typical bug. In a second session run a copy command in a while loop (cp .lib/libphp7.a /apache/modules/ ) before make install.